Wine doesn't run 64-bit program
Sorry if it's obvious, but I've been going back and forth with this without solving it:
I have a program both in 32-bit and 64-bit versions. The 32-bit works, with this output from wine:
007c:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
007c:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
007c:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
007c:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
0024:fixme:richedit:editor_handle_message EM_SETMARGINS: stub
0024:fixme:richedit:editor_handle_message EM_SETMARGINS: stub
0024:fixme:shell:InitNetworkAddressControl stub


For the 64-bit one, however, it doesn't open the file, with this output:
0128:err:module:import_dll Loading library VCOMP90.DLL (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\erick\\Stata\\StataMP-64.exe") failed (error c000007b).
0128:err:module:loader_init Importing dlls for L"Z:\\home\\erick\\Stata\\StataMP-64.exe" failed, status c0000135


Also, this is the output for apt list --installed | grep wine:

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

libwine/jammy,now 6.0.3~repack-1 i386 [installed,automatic]
wine-stable-amd64/jammy,now 9.0.0.0~jammy-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
wine-stable-i386/jammy,now 9.0.0.0~jammy-1 i386 [installed,automatic]
wine-stable/jammy,now 9.0.0.0~jammy-1 amd64 [installed]
wine32/jammy,now 6.0.3~repack-1 i386 [installed]
winehq-stable/jammy,now 9.0.0.0~jammy-1 amd64 [installed]


I've already deleted and reinstalled wine, added VCOMP90.DLL to the same folder, but nothing worked. Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but could someone help?

Check with https://www.winehq.org. Not all Windows programs are available through wine. This is not a Ubuntu problem, this is a wine problem.
